# How can I use my iPhone's contacts with the new Google Maps?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, google-maps

The [new Google Maps app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8) seems like a good substitute for the inbuilt Maps app, as has been discussed ad nauseam. However, one drawback it exhibits over the inbuilt app is that it doesn't seem to directly integrate with your contacts - and doesn't seem to integrate with any contacts you have stored with Google Contacts/Gmail either (in my case, I sync them with my iPhone, so they are the same set). Are there any workarounds or hacks which can be used to get it do this? The best I've found so far is the obvious - to open the contacts app, copy the postcode (I am in the UK so that's typically precise enough for navigation) and paste it into Google Maps. Is there anything simpler/quicker?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this app, [Contacts for Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/app/contacts-for-google-maps/id592746575?mt=8).

It can create links inside your Contacts that will open the address directly in the Google Maps app.

**Edit:** I wrote the app.

Comment: Tomislav, thanks. It looks like you wrote that app. You should modify your answer to make it clear you have a vested interest, especially since you are charging for it. That would avoid any accusations of bias.

Comment: One of the reviews on the apple website says that it pulls up the location just great but doesn't allow one to get directions from there... is this still the case?

Comment: The app will open Google Maps with the address selected. Then you tap the car icon in the lower right and you get directions. I'm not sure what's the problem that user is having. BTW, you can try it yourself by searching for an  address in Google Maps. I just use their URL scheme API to open the address.